# How did the Beis Din have the authority to relax the rules of Muktza?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, muktzeh, sanhedrin, halachic-development

Shulchan Aruch HaRav ([O.C. 310:16](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/308/16)) lays out the general history of the prohibition of Mukza (Based on [Shabbos 123b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=123b&format=pdf)):

> בימי נחמיה בן חכליה שהיו העם מזלזלים באיסורי שבת כמ"ש בימים ההם ראיתי ביהודה דורכי[ם] גתות בשבת ומביאים הערימות וגו' עשו חכמים סיג וגדר לאיסור הוצאה וגזרו על כל הכלים אע"פ שמלאכתם להיתר שלא לטלטלם כלל אפילו לצורך תשמישן המיוחד להם חוץ מן כוסות וקערות וסכין וכיוצא בהם מהכלים הצריכים ביותר לסעודת השבת.
>
> ואח"כ כשראו חכמים שחזרו העם להזהר קצת באיסורי שבת חזרו והתירו לטלטל כל כלי שמלאכתו להיתר לצורך גופו או לצורך מקומו.
>
> ואח"כ כשראו שחזרו העם להזהר יותר חזרו והתירו לטלטל כל כלי שמלאכתו להיתר אפילו לצורך הכלי עצמו אבל לטלטל שלא לצורך כלל עדיין לא נמנו עליו חכמים להתירו ונשאר עומד באיסורו שנאסר בגזרת חכמים שבימי נחמיה בן חכליה

To summarize:

> In the days of Nechemia, due to a general severe laxity in keeping Shabbos, all vessels were prohibited except a limited number of types necessary to eat the meal. This was done as a סיג וגדר לאיסור הוצאה - a fence around the prohibition of carrying. This prohibition was subsequently relaxed, ultimately to Muktza as it is today.

Although I haven't found anything definitive on exactly *when* the prohibition was relaxed, it does seem that this was not in the times of Nechemia's Beis Din (but if something definitive could be found otherwise, that would answer the question).

However, The Rambam writes ([Mamrim 2:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=81&perek=2&halocha=3&hilite=)):

> דברים שראו בית דין לגזור ולאסרן לעשות סייג אם פשט איסורן בכל [ישראל] אין בית דין גדול אחר יכול לעקרן ולהתירן אפילו היה גדול מן הראשונים
>
> Things which a Beis Din saw fit to degree and forbid to do as a fence - if the prohibition spread to all of Israel another Great Beis Din (i.e. a Sanhedrin) cannot remove it and permit it, even if they were greater than the first ones.

If so, how could the prohibition have been subsequently relaxed?

Comment: I feel like these questions always get answered (without historical evidence) with "it was originally enacted such that these would be allowed" ie כולא חדא גזירה היא.

Comment: Who says it was פשט איסורן בכל ישראל?

Comment: @wfb, well it certainly is now, so if someone says it wasn't, that could be, although it would be odd since its objective was being met, as Shabbos observance was improving.

Comment: @wfb Would the chachamim have needed to be matir had it not? And would the heter reasoning be portrayed solely as: שחזרו העם להזהר קצת באיסורי שבת?

Comment: @Loewian yes, אם פשט איסורן בכל [ישראל] אין בית דין גדול אחר יכול לעקרן ולהתירן, but if it was not פשט then they can be מתיר

Comment: @Loewian As you see from the case of שמן as well

Answer (score 8):

The [Aruch Hashulchan (308:3-5)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%97) quotes Tosafos in Bava Kama who says that it was initially only a temporary enactment: 
בימי נחמיה בן חכליה שהיו פרוצים בחילול שבתות מהזמן שהיו בבבל, עמד הוא ועזרא וחגי זכריה ומלאכי ואנשי כנסת הגדולה וגזרו על דורם עוד חומרות, ולא התירו רק ג' כלים. ולא היתה גזירות קבועות לדורות, וכן כתבו מפורש רבותינו בעלי התוספות בבבא קמא (צ"ד: ד"ה 'בימי'), שלא גזרו זה רק על דור זה. ולכן אחר כך כשראו שחזרו להזהר בשבת - התירו וחזרו והתירו עד שנשאר כפי הדינים הקודמים וכפי ההלכה אצל[י]נו

Comment: Actually, #4 hints at a broader answer, that it is really part of establishing Shabbos as the Torah says, which Mamrim 2:1 says is allowed by subsequent Beis Dins. Anyway, SAH doesn't seem to hold of the answer as you bring it, otherwise he wouldn't attribute the prohibition to Nechemia, since it was only for that generation. But it is an answer to the broader question, so +1.